# Disable mobile location in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, location

I have a flutter project and I would like to may enable and disabled mobile location throught my app. I'm using the library Geolocator but this one allows me to enable location but I can't disable location with this library.
is there any other library that allows me to disable location?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can try to **permission_handler** this packages to check permission user can give already permission than location permission can not giving.